# iOS 9/Swift: Dilemma with tableView's scrollEnabled

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiview, scrollview, gesture

I embeded a custom `UIView` class called **DrawView** into the contentView of tableView cells, this allows my users to draw paths (`UIBezierPath`) in each tableView cell with their finger tips.

As you can imagine, the user wants to use their fingers to draw both horizontal and vertical lines/path in each cell, however, they are not able to draw vertical paths unless I disable the `scrollEnabled` property of the tableView:

```
tableView.scrollEnabled = false
```

With this, I can draw paths of any direction in the tableview cell; however, I can not scroll down the tableview any more (unsurprisingly). I think I can create a button that calls `scrollToRowAtIndexPath` method on the tableview, but I would like to know if there's any better way to do this by **re-enabling** `scrollEnabled` depending on certain gesture or the location of the user's finger tip on the screen.

I've attached a screenshot of my custom UIView **DrawView** for drawing paths:

[image: DrawView UIView class]

Comment: Do you have and event of didStartDrawing and didEndDrawing in your DrawView ?

Comment: Thanks for the inspiration @RanHassid! I just added these two delegate methods to my DrawView, and these helped me to turn on/off `tableView.scrollEnabled`. Problem solved!

Comment: Cool glad that it works for you ...